# custom ubuntu live CD: NetworkManager not working

Tags: networking, network-manager, live-cd, chroot, live-environment

I'm trying to build up an ubuntu live cd from scratch but I'm failing with the automatic configuration for the network interface card.
The live cd is booting into desktop but NetworkManager is stuck to be unconfigured. The configuration /etc/network/interfaces is untouched, therefore it should be configured by NetworkManager but it is not. When the desktop environment is loading, NetworkManager is disabled with no connection configured.

What's wrong with my configuration?

---

For reproducing - how I build my live cd:

you need:

```
apt install build-essential debootstrap squashfs-tools genisoimage syslinux-common syslinux-utils
```

now copy base system from original iso:

```
mount -o loop kubuntu-16.10-desktop-amd64.iso /mnt/tmp/
mkdir -p /usr/local/src/custom-ubuntu/iso && cd /usr/local/src/custom-ubuntu/iso
cp -r /mnt/tmp/.disk/ .
cp -r /mnt/tmp/boot/ .
cp -r /mnt/tmp/isolinux/ .
cp -r /mnt/tmp/EFI/ .
mkdir casper
```

create mini-ubuntu

```
debootstrap --arch amd64 yakkety /usr/local/src/custom-ubuntu/squashfs
```

mount devices and chroot into squashfs

```
cd /usr/local/src/custom-ubuntu/
mount --bind /dev squashfs/dev
mount -t devpts devpts squashfs/dev/pts
mount -t proc proc squashfs/proc
mount -t sysfs sysfs squashfs/sys
cp /etc/resolv.conf squashfs/etc/
cp /etc/apt/sources.list squashfs/etc/
chroot squashfs
```

install your favorite programs for your live cd. In my case this is

```
apt install bash-completion ssh vim gpm htop iotop cifs-utils ntp mc rar unrar unace arj p7zip-full apt-file lsb-release dmidecode hdparm realpath acpid aptitude unzip ncdu di localepurge console-data gnu-fdisk intel-microcode amd64-microcode sysstat bc unattended-upgrades btrfs-progs btrfs-tools hfsplus hfsprogs hfsutils exfat-fuse exfat-utils ntfs-3g gparted gpart gddrescue linux-image-generic linux-signed-generic linux-signed-image-generic linux-firmware  linux-base linux-tools-generic linux-wlan-ng linux-headers-generic grub-efi casper lupin-casper ubiquity-casper firefox okular libreoffice libreoffice-kde gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-breeze k4dirstat meld partitionmanager gsmartcontrol 
apt clean
```

Install your favorite desktop environment.

leave chroot and copy the new kernel

```
cp squashfs/boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-27-generic iso/casper/initrd.lz
cp squashfs/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-generic iso/casper/vmlinuz.efi
```

umount and clean up:

```
umount squashfs/dev/pts
umount squashfs/dev
umount squashfs/proc
umount squashfs/sys
rm squashfs/etc/resolv.conf
```

Now you are finished and it is time to build the squash-filesystem and create the iso file:

```
mksquashfs squashfs iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs -noappend
genisoimage -cache-inodes -r -J -joliet-long -input-charset utf-8 -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e boot/grub/efi.img -no-emul-boot -o live.iso iso
isohybrid -u live.iso
```